# Trouble Connecting to SSIS in SQL Server 2017 (14.0.1)

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2017

Setting up a new server with SQL Server 2017 (14.0.1000) and I just installed SSIS (14.0). As of right now I am unable to connect to SSIS from SSMS and receiving the following error message:

```
Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "localhost" failed with the following error: "Class not registered".

This error can occur when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current version of the SQL Server tools. Instead, add folders to the service configuration file to let the local Integration Services service manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.


For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506689
```

I've confirmed that the versions are compatible, tried doing an uninstall/reinstall of SSIS, all the while confirming SSIS is running in SQL configuration manager, but still the problem persists.

Update: I've also tried following the steps here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/hh213130(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
to no avail.

Comment: What version of SSMS?

Comment: @JacobH I am using SSMS 18.4

Comment: Try with SSMS 17.9.1 (or whatever came with the SQL Server 2017 installer you used).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't actually install SQL on this server (this was done by a 'systems engineer') - am I able to just install SSMS 17.xx and connect with that instead?

Comment: Yes, the older versions of SSMS can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#previous-ssms-releases) and can be installed side-by-side with each other.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else has a similar setup with **SQL Server 2017 (14.0.1000) and SSIS (14.0)** as of the creation of this question/answer **SSMS 18.4** will not allow you to connect to SSIS. The only fix I have found is following Jacob's suggestion and downloading **SSMS 17.9** which resolved the issue.

Comment: Yes, as you have found (and I have as well) it appears that SSMS is only backwards compatible with the SQL Server engine itself, and not any of the related services.